# My simple Spring boot project Docker container problems

Tags: java, docker

My docker-compose.yml file

```
  version: "3.9"
  services:
    webapp:
     image: springbootproject
       build: .
     ports:
       - "8085:8085"
     depends_on:
       - postgres
       - pgadmin
   postgres:
      container_name: postgres_container
 image: postgres
 environment:
   POSTGRES_USER: postgres
   POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 12345
   PGDATA: /data/postgres
volumes:
   - postgres:/data/postgres
 ports:
  - "5432:5432"
networks:
  - postgres
restart: unless-stopped

 pgadmin:
   container_name: pgadmin_container
   image: dpage/pgadmin4
 environment:
   PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
   PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
   PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
volumes:
   - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin

ports:
  - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-80}:80"
networks:
  - postgres
restart: unless-stopped

networks:
   postgres:
     driver: bridge

volumes:
 postgres:
 pgadmin:
```

Dockerfile

```
  FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot
  ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
  COPY ${JAR_FILE} springmvcrestapi.jar
  EXPOSE 8085
  ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","springmvcrestapi.jar"]
```

Hi everyone my simple project using docker inteelij ide terminal writing docker-compose up postgre and pgadmin working container  but my project images  **Error: Unable to access jarfile springmvcrestapi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar** What is the problem ??

Comment: Ditch your `Dockefile` instead run `mvn spring-boot:build-image` to let Spring Boot build the image, saves you the hassle.

Comment: not working mvn spring-boot:build-image same errors

Comment: As stated delete the `Dockerfile` and run the build. If you leave the dockerfile it will be used instead.

Comment: Not working Deinum

Comment: What user are you running inside the container and does that user have permissions to run the JAR? Also, can you verify that the JAR is copied successfully? You can run `docker run -it --entrypoint bash <image_name>` to explore the container.